# installing geth on Mac, --devel option error?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to install geth from my Terminal, my Mac is running Big Sur 11.5.2. Here are the commands Im using:

```bash
brew tap ethereum/ethereum 
brew install ethereum --devel
```

However, the second command causes the following error: `Error: invalid option: --devel`

I have tried using `brew install ethereum` as a second line before running `brew install ethereum --devel`, but get the same error. Any idea how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: why do u need geth?

Comment: @MajdTL I am following an online class (posted two months ago), and I have to download geth and include the developer tools option.

Comment: Can anyone update on this ? This is the same problem that I am getting whenever I am trying to install --devel in geth and I am always getting an error as posted in the question. Can anyone please help ?